# How to connect to a gcloud instance and run a command either on startup or consecutively in one line

Tags: google-cloud-platform, debian, startup, gnu-screen, gnu-parallel

I'm trying to run a command when I start my gcloud vm server. I added the following command in the console custom metadata 
key:

```
startup-script
```

value:

```
#! /bin/bash
parallel 'screen -d -m python3 Documents/myscript.py' ::: arg1 arg2
```

But when I start the vm instance, it doesn't run because I don't see any screens when I type `screen -list`. However, when I connect with the gcp tool over SSH using the following command to connect

```
gcloud beta compute ssh --zone "us-west1-c" "instance-1" --project "unique-kakaw-123456"
```

and then run

```
parallel 'screen -d -m python3 Documents/myscript.py' ::: arg1 arg2
```

consecutively, it runs properly.

How do I either, get my script to run on start up on gcp, or failing which, use the gcloud command to run the command in the same line so then when I hit enter, it will connect to the server and run the command right after. Because if I put both the above commands in the same line and add a ; it won't work obviously.

For some reason, I can add the script to rc.d and update on my ubuntu pc at home and it works fine. I don't know why it doesn't work on gcp.

Comment: I don't think what you are trying to do is possible. Startup scripts do not have a TTY (terminal window). Therefore what can screen attach to? Look at the serial port output for your instance and trace what happens. Edit your post to ask about one problem, feel free to create multiple questions. For your gcloud question create a new question as that is an answer by itself. gcloud just launch ssh. The command input to ssh has nothing to do with gcloud.

Comment: Is there a way to run my script in parallel with different arguments without using screen then?

Comment: Follow my advice and create multiple questions.

Comment: Okay I’ll have to think it thought I’m not sure how to split up the questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## The startup script should be working. Here's what could be happening:

### 1. Python script is not being executed because it cannot be found

[Compute Engine documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript?hl=en_US#startup_script_execution) says:

> The instance always executes startup scripts as root after the network is available.

So, if the Python script is in your home directory, provide the full path (replace *[USER]* with the actual user):

```
#! /bin/bash
parallel 'screen -d -m python3 /home/[USER]/Documents/myscript.py' ::: arg1 arg2
```

### 2. Python script runs and then exits, so screen terminates the window

[Screen's User Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html#Overview) says:

> When a program terminates, screen (per default) kills the window that contained it. If this window was in the foreground, the display switches to the previously displayed window; if none are left, screen exits.

Thus if your Python script exits prematurely, add this to your */etc/screenrc*:

```
zombie qr
```

[Here is what this parameter does:](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html#Zombie)

> When a string of two keys is specified to the zombie command, ‘dead’ windows will remain in the list.

---

For the record, I replicated your startup script configuration in my GCP instance (providing the full path) and I can confirm it does work: there were two *screens* running with my Python script, each with its own argument.

Comment: So I did everything you said, I added the zombie line. The key for the custom metadata should be startup-script correct? And the script should run when I turn on the server correct?

Comment: It doesn't seem to work, maybe I'm missing something else?

Comment: Yes, the key for the custom metadata is startup-script, and it should run when you turn on the server. After adding the zombie parameter, do you see the screen processes?